# Can't access ResizableArray's protected method, swap, from subclass, ArrayBuffer?

Tags: scala

ArrayBuffer extends ResizableArray which include a protected method, swap. Yet I can't access swap. What am I missing?

```
scala> import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

scala> val x=new ArrayBuffer[Int]() 
x: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int] = ArrayBuffer()

scala> x+=3

scala> x+=5

scala> x.swap(0,1)
<console>:7: error: method swap cannot be accessed in scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int]
       x.swap(0,1)
         ^
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/api/scala/collection/mutable/ResizableArray.html#swap%28Int%2CInt%29), `swap` is declared as a protected method - which means that while you could access it within the code of `ArrayBuffer` (or any other class derived from `ResizableArray`),  you can't access it from other class.

From the [Scala Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf), page 57:

> The protected modifier applies to
>   class member definitions. Protected
>   members of a class can be accessed
>   from within
>   – the template of the defining class,
>   – all templates that have the defining class as a base class,
>   – the companion module of any of those classes.

You're not in any of those contexts, which is why you're seeing an error.

Comment: Yes, protected means that the subclass, ArrayBuffer, could call the protected superclass function swap(). It does not mean that instances of the subclass create public access to protected superclass methods.